# How to handle dependency in maven project?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I have a project **A** which has **B** as parent in it's pom.xml and I am getting all the dependencies. Now I need a `class P` which has been defined in project **X** and I can use that only if I include **Y** as a parent (so I think it is case of transitive dependency, though I am not sure if this is a correct understanding).

Now as my project **A** already has a parent defined so I cannot define **Y** in the same pom.xml and hence I am not able to get the `class P` in project **A**. I tried adding **X** as normal dependency but I am getting `cannot resolve dependency` while building project.

How can I handle this ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a class of `X`, you need to declare `X` as dependency, not as parent.

Comment: Yes I added ```X ``` as a dependency only but it does not compile. But if I see the usage in other projects where we have Y as a parent, then adding X as a dependency works. BUT like I said, I cannot define Y as a parent as my project already has a different parent.

Comment: Maybe `Y` defines additional repositories that you need. Try to find that out and then put those repositories in your `settings.xml`.

Comment: Nah that can't be the case because same settings.xml work if I try to use the project which already uses X as a dependency.

Comment: So, I thought this project hat `Y` as parent? Parent POMs can define additional repositories. Furthermore, it would be good if you could add the complete error message to your question.

Comment: All that was missing was to add the version. As the version was being fetched from Y and I was not adding Y in my project, it was failing. Sorry for the silly question.